# Is there a free and privacy-aware alternative to Google?

Tags: webapp-rec, privacy

Google *tracks searches* and also sends search data to visited sites in the *HTTP referrer headers*. This information can be tied together to *allow someone to look at what you have been searching* over multiple queries (for example, see [AOL search data leak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AOL_search_data_scandal)).

Are there any *decent* alternatives to Google that place a higher emphasis on *privacy*? And what makes this alternative better, or what does it do differently?

Comment: Closely related: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2792/google-search-engine-alternatives

Comment: using the HTTPS link of google prevents the HTTP referrer header. Besides, I am much more worried about my ISP nosing around my internet usage than Google.

Comment: Ouch, that is a good point - I didn't think about the ISPs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google now has SSL support, so use https://www.google.com. Referrer headers are not sent to the pages you go to from SSL search results, nor are search queries snoopable.

If you want to minimize tracking, block cookies from *.google.com, explicitly enabling cookies for at least mail.google.com, if you use GMail.

Comment: Cheers - added it in to my search providers as https://www.google.com/#hl=en&q=%s

Comment: "Note that SSL search does not reduce the data that Google receives and logs when you search, or change the listing of these terms in your Web History ." from [this page](http://www.google.com/support/websearch/bin/answer.py?answer=173733&hl=en).

Comment: I don't think this is a privacy-conscious solution at all... Better use StartPage or DuckDuckGo, for instance.

Answer (score 4):

[DuckDuckGo](https://duckduckgo.com/) [claims](http://duckduckgo.com/privacy.html) not to not track your searching.

I've only used it a little but find it's good if a little short on results sometimes, would allow this since it seems very new and it provides easy link to google if short changed.

I've noticed stackoverflow have added this to their search options which must give it some kudos.  That said I cannot say it makes a better alternative but it is a decent alternative.

Comment: Thanks, I must say I have used it before and loved it - except I wish the page used a bit more real estate and maybe that the results were a bit better. I love the feature where you select what topic you are looking at if the search is ambiguous: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=apple

Comment: Actually I'm getting quite very decent results with DDG, and sometimes better than Google. See also: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/73312/are-duckduckgo-redirects-a-privacy-issue

Answer (score 1):

Try https://ssl.scroogle.org/.  It's basically a tunnel to Google that strips out your personal information.  Has a Firefox search plugin, too.

Comment: Thanks for that - any chance you know the url search format so that I can add it to my Chrome search engines list?

Comment: The Firefox search plugin uses this:

<os:Url type="text/html" method="POST" template="https://ssl.scroogle.org/cgi-bin/nbbwssl.cgi">
  <os:Param name="Gw" value="{searchTerms}"/>
</os:Url>

Answer (score 0):

The Chrome Search Engine URL for https://ssl.scroogle.org is

```
https://ssl.scroogle.org/cgi-bin/nbbwssl.cgi?Gw=%s
```

Answer (score 0):

[StartPage](https://startpage.com/) allows to perform searches using Google but [without the privacy downsides](https://startpage.com/eng/protect-privacy.html).

StartPage will send the search query to and fetch results from the Google search engine, crucially without saving the users' IP addresses or giving any personal user information to Google's servers. StartPage is the default search engine in the Tor Browser.